# Text field displays "undefined" php database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to create a form where when the user inputs the account code in one text field, the account name should auto-generate in the next text field. The database and table are already set up but when the user inputs the account code, the account name field displays "undefined". I'm new to coding and I'm not sure how to solve this issue. Below I've attached what my form looks like, the javascript code and PHP code.
**myform**

[image: myform]

Script:

```
// onkeyup event will occur when the user 
        // release the key and calls the function
        // assigned to this event
        function GetDetail(str) {
            if (str.length == 0) {
                document.getElementById("account_name").value = "";
                return;
            }
            else {
  
                // Creates a new XMLHttpRequest object
                var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  
                    // Defines a function to be called when
                    // the readyState property changes
                    if (this.readyState == 4 && 
                            this.status == 200) {
                          
                        // Typical action to be performed
                        // when the document is ready
                        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  
                        // Returns the response data as a
                        // string and store this array in
                        // a variable assign the value 
                        // received to first name input field
                          
                        document.getElementById
                        ("account_name").value = myObj[1];
                          
                    }
                };
  
                // xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
                xmlhttp.open("GET", "cashVoucher.acc.php?user_id=" + str, true);
                  
                // Sends the request to the server
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        }
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  
// Get the user id 
$account_code = $_REQUEST['account_code'];
  
// Database connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "general_ledger_account");
  
if ($user_id !== "") {
      
    // Get corresponding first name and 
    // last name for that user id    
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT account_name FROM ledger_account WHERE account_code='$account_code'");
 

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
  
    // Get the first name
    $name = $row["account_name"];
  
   
}
  
// Store it in a array
$result = array("$name");
  
// Send in JSON encoded form
$myJSON = json_encode($result);
echo $myJSON;
?>
```

Form:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Account Code</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="account_code" name="account_code" placeholder="Debit or Credit Account Code" onkeyup="GetDetail(this.value)" value="">
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Account Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="account_name" name="account_name"  placeholder="Debit or Credit Account Name" value="">
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in javascript is zero-indexed, so the index for first item is `0`, so the code should be:

```js
document.getElementById("account_name").value = myObj[0];
```

Comment: Yes I did that. When I put 0, the code does not work. As if in if I enter my account code the account name does not generate any data.

Comment: @SimiJK put `console.log(myObj);` before the code above and see the output in your browser console. It will help to know the structure of your data.

Comment: I don't see any difference. Still the same.

Comment: check `console.log(this.responseText);` after first if

Comment: I cant see the output as the form saves the data back to my DB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace user_id with account_code in script code and php code also and change myObj[1] to myObj[0]
see the updated code

```
<?php


// Get the user id 
$account_code = $_REQUEST['account_code'];
  
// Database connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "general_ledger_account");
  
if ($account_code !== "") {
      
    // Get corresponding first name and 
    // last name for that user id    
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT account_name FROM ledger_account WHERE account_code='$account_code'");
 

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
  
    // Get the first name
    $name = $row["account_name"];
  
   
}
  
// Store it in a array
$result = array("$name");
  
// Send in JSON encoded form
$myJSON = json_encode($result);
echo $myJSON;
?>
```

Javascript code

```
// onkeyup event will occur when the user 
    // release the key and calls the function
    // assigned to this event
    function GetDetail(str) {
        if (str.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById("account_name").value = "";
            return;
        }
        else {

            // Creates a new XMLHttpRequest object
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

                // Defines a function to be called when
                // the readyState property changes
                if (this.readyState == 4 && 
                        this.status == 200) {
                      
                    // Typical action to be performed
                    // when the document is ready
                    var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                    // Returns the response data as a
                    // string and store this array in
                    // a variable assign the value 
                    // received to first name input field
                      
                    document.getElementById
                    ("account_name").value = myObj[0];
                      
                }
            };

            // xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
            xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.php?account_code=" + str, true);
              
            // Sends the request to the server
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
```